# Fire an event on the original thread inside of an AsyncCallback (Console App)

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, synchronization, threadpool

I am using Func<> or Action<>.BeginInvoke to run methods asynchronously using the ThreadPool.

Is it possible to have the AsyncCallback invoke a function (or an event, technically) on the original thread that spawned the new thread?

I know that in WinForms apps you can use Control / ISynchronizeInvoke / Dispatcher to alert the UI thread when async operations complete -- but this isn't a WinForms app and it does not seem to work.

```
    class SyncTest : System.ComponentModel.ISynchronizeInvoke
    {
        public void TestMethod() {
            Console.WriteLine(System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId + " Test Method Fired.");
        }

        public IAsyncResult BeginInvoke(Delegate method, object[] args) {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public object EndInvoke(IAsyncResult result) {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public object Invoke(Delegate method, object[] args) {
            return method.DynamicInvoke(args); 
        }

        public bool InvokeRequired {
            get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
        }

        public void Test()
        {
            var sleep = new Action(() => System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000));

            System.ComponentModel.ISynchronizeInvoke originalThreadCallback = (System.ComponentModel.ISynchronizeInvoke)this;

            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            {
                sleep.BeginInvoke(new AsyncCallback(res =>
                {
                    (res.AsyncState as Action).EndInvoke(res);
                    Console.WriteLine("Thread inside callback: " + System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId); 
                    originalThreadCallback.Invoke(new Action(() => this.TestMethod()), null);
                }), sleep);
            }
        }
    }
```

The output from the Test() method is as follows:

Main thread = 9

TEST DONE

Thread inside callback: 11

Thread inside callback: 10

10 Test Method Fired.

11 Test Method Fired.

Thread inside callback: 12

12 Test Method Fired.

Thread inside callback: 13

13 Test Method Fired.

Thread inside callback: 14

14 Test Method Fired.

As you can see nothing is invoked on the original thread with ID = 9.

Obviously my implementation of ISynchronizeInvoke isn't actually doing anything to invoke the Test Method on the original thread, and thats the problem -- but I also can't seem to get an ISynchronizeInvoke instance out of any of my delegates or events (it is always null). What objects in .NET 4 implement the interface correctly?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you'd have to have some sort of loop, just like Windows Forms (etc) do, waiting for work to process.

You *could* write that yourself, but it would mean your original thread would have to be kept relatively free, just like you don't want to block the UI thread in a Windows Forms app. Basically, you'd be rewriting some of the infrastructure that WinForms uses. There's nothing I'm aware of that just does that out of the box, although the .NET 4 producer/consumer queue classes (e.g. [`BlockingCollection<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267312.aspx)) would at least *help*.

The docs for `BlockingCollection<T>` give a quick example of how to implement a producer/consumer queue - basically your threadpool threads would call `Add` on the queue, and your consumer thread would call `Take` on it (or `TryTake`).

There's also a [Channel-9 video](http://channel9.msdn.com/Blogs/philpenn/BlockingCollectionT-Demonstration-in-Producer-Consumer-Scenarios) with expert Stephen Toub (of the parallel team in MS) about using `BlockingCollection`.

Comment: Basically I want one thread thats devoted to doing some IO operations (file IO mostly). My reasoning is that in a concurrent environment I would have to lock() those operations anyway, so might as well have one thread receive event notifications from various asynchronous thread pool threads, and act accordingly. I see what you mean that the thread has to be relatively free -- basically I would only want that thread to react to events coming from other threads and thats its only purpose.

Comment: @SeanThoman: Well it sounds like you basically just want a producer/consumer queue dedicated to this then. It doesn't really matter whether the thread that initially spawned the work is the consumer, you just want to add work to the queue. What version of .NET are you using?

Comment: @JohnSkeet: Thats true, it doesnt really matter if its the original thread, just want one thread thats devoted to handling events synchronously (basically an event loop, I think). The idea is that threads doing other work shouldn't have to wait for IO that would be locked() anyway. I am using .NET 4.

Comment: @SeanThoman: Okay, it's good to know you're using .NET 4. You should consider using `Task<T>` to schedule work rather than `BeginInvoke` - it's simpler in various ways :) Anyway, I've edited my answer with some links... I suspect `BlockingCollection<T>` is going to be the way forward for you.